# JButton default cursor

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

**Is there a way to set default cursor of `JButton` components?**

This is how to set cursor for a one `JButton`:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");
btn.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

According [lookAndFeel Nimbus defaults](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) there's no a property like "*Button.cursor*".

I'd like to set default cursor once so all the JButtons in the app have the same hand-cursor when the mouse cursor moves over.

Comment: The short answer is no. You "could" try using an `AwtEventListener` and monitor all the `mouseMoved` (`entered`) events, check the source of the event to see if it's a `JButton` and if it's cursor isn't set to `HAND_CURSOR` update it.  Equally, you could make you own custom button and replace all the buttons in you app with it...

Comment: Maybe a custom `ButtonUI` derived from the nimbus one (assuming by the question you're using that), and set that in the `UIDefaults`. Then attach a mouse listener for the enter and leave events in the `ButtonUI`. That way it would be used for all the buttons that do not explicitly use another UI delegate.

Comment: *"all the JButtons in the app have the same hand-cursor when the mouse cursor moves over."*  How should they react when the user tabs through them?

Comment: Cursor came from setting in Native OS, hasn't something with Nimbus, Metal ... any LookAndFeel (some custom L&Fa to modify that), override events from ButtonModel (easiest by add ChangeListener)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a `custom button` that extends the `JButton` and use that. Some thing like :

**MyCustomJButton.java**

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyCustomJButton extends JButton implements MouseListener
{

    private Cursor defaultCursor;
    private Cursor handCursor;

    public MyCustomJButton()
    {
        super();

        init();
    }

    public MyCustomJButton(Action a)
    {
        super(a);

        init();
    }

    public MyCustomJButton(Icon icon)
    {
        super(icon);

        init();
    }

    public MyCustomJButton(String text, Icon icon)
    {
        super(text, icon);

        init();
    }

    public MyCustomJButton(String text)
    {
        super(text);

        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        this.setCursor(handCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        this.setCursor(defaultCursor);
    }

    private void init()
    {
        defaultCursor = this.getCursor();
        handCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);

        addMouseListener(this);
    }

}
```

Once you have implemented your own custom button, you can instantiate it like you would instantiate the `JButton`.

```
MyCustomJButton myButton = new MyCustomJButton("My Button");
```

Comment: all those event are implemented in ButtonModel, and then you missed event from keyboard